# How to suppress "The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface."?

Tags: php, node.js

I have a third party node module, that uses the old `sys` naming scheme, and a third party PHP module that decides, whether node has been running successfully based on its output. And it seems like that warning is considered a failure, which causes an exception. I would like not to change any vendor code, e.g. not replace sys with util and not make PHP aware that this warning isn't critical. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question carefully the first time.

Comment: So you cannot control the 3rd party node module nor the 3rd party PHP module? What exactly can you control in the process..?

Comment: @alessioalex, node.js configuration

Comment: If the node module is calling require('sys') internally anywhere (and you can't / don't want to change this), there's nothing you can do about it. You must be able to change either the node module (that's causing the warning) or the PHP module that decided wheather it's a success or a failure.

Comment: @alessioalex, so I guess the answer to the question is "no", it's a pity. By the way, here is the relevant code: https://github.com/Behat/Mink/blob/master/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/Zombie/Server.php#L191

Comment: You haven't told us what the "PHP module" is, which would go a long ways to knowing if there is a config option to change the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is easy.

Find the third party module on github, fork it, replace all references of `sys` with `util` and make a pull request.

Then either wait for it to be pulled in or use your own fork in your code.

Comment: I'd rather fix the PHP module. In this case both modules are on github, but that's not always the case.

Comment: But the problem isn't with PHP. This problem that `sys` is deprecated needs to be _fixed_ by _someone_ at _some point_. Why don't _you_ fix it _now_ ?

Comment: +1 for fixing the problem; Fluffy, you use the modules someone else took the time to build, make the fix and contribute it back; then you don't have to deal with the error or customizing third party modules.

Comment: I would gladly do something like that in my spare time, but you know, sometimes people don't appreciate employees choosing to spend a lot more time fixing stuff, because it's the right thing, instead of just making the thing work now.

Comment: @Fluffy I could have fixed it already in the last hour. Feel free to promote the short term solution of _hacking_ the PHP module to make it "work". But that's increasing code debt. And I would hate to have employees who purposely increase code debt.

Comment: So fixing that would take you an hour, ok. How long would it take to fix the PHP module? 2 minutes? The original problem seems to be caused more by a ridiculous decision to output the deprecation message to stdout without an option to suppress that. Imagine PHP adding stuff like that to the browser window for every deprecated thing.

Comment: Besides, I'm not sure this is more code dept, than "fixing" node - if its developers don't care / have another version, their updates will conflict with my changes and require even more time in the future to resolve in case of merge.

Comment: @Fluffy that would be a great design decision. It would force PHP devs to fix their damn broken code. There is nothing wrong piping messages to stdout. Now there would be a problem with piping those messages to stderr.

Comment: @Raynos, right, so now when a developer decides to rename stuff, the code that uses the old name becomes "damn broken code"?

Comment: @Fluffy It's been deprecated since 0.2. Anyway, you've already solved the problem. Either fix it in PHP or node, you can make that choice yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own error handler using [`set_error_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and in that handler simply ignore that particular warning, assuming it's not a fatal one.

Comment: PHP module execution stops after it throws an exception, so this won't work. I guess I need some sort of node configuration trick